# Multiple JavaScript timeouts at the same moment

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I'm developing an HTML5 application and I'm drawing a sequence of images on the canvas with a certain speed and a certain timeout between every animation.

Able to use it multiple times I've made a function for it.

```
var imgNumber = 0;
var lastImgNumber = 0;
var animationDone = true;

function startUpAnimation(context, imageArray, x, y, timeOut, refreshFreq) {
    if (lastImgNumber == 0) lastImgNumber = imageArray.length-1;

    if (animationDone) {
        animationDone = false;
        setTimeout(playAnimationSequence, timeOut, refreshFreq);
    }
    context.drawImage(imageArray[imgNumber], x, y);
}

function playAnimationSequence(interval) {
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (imgNumber >= lastImgNumber) {
            imgNumber = 0;
            clearInterval(timer);
            animationDone = true;
        } else imgNumber++;
    }, interval);
}
```

Now in my main code, every time startUpAnimation with the right parameters it works just fine. **But when I want to draw multiple animations on the screen at the same time with each of them at a different interval and speed it doesnt work!**

```
startUpAnimation(context, world.mushrooms, canvas.width / 3, canvas.height - (canvas.height / 5.3), 5000, 300);
startUpAnimation(context, world.clouds, 100, 200, 3000, 100);
```

It now displays both animations at the right location but they animate both at the interval and timeout of the first one called, so in my case 5000 timeout and 300 interval.

How do I fix this so that they all play independently? I think I need to make it a class or something but I have no idea how to fix this. In some cases I even need to display maybe 5 animations at the same time with this function.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You've only got one `imgNumber`, one `lastImgNumber`, and one `animationDone` variable for two animations.

Comment: How is it supposed to animate anything? You are drawing only once from each call, the interval only increments a variable but does nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
            var Class = function () {
            this.imgNumber = 0;
            this.lastImgNumber = 0;
            this.animationDone = true;

        }
        Class.prototype.startUpAnimation = function(context, imageArray, x, y, timeOut, refreshFreq) {
            //     if (lastImgNumber == 0) lastImgNumber = imageArray.length-1;

            if (this.animationDone) {
                this.animationDone = false;
                setTimeout(this.playAnimationSequence, timeOut, refreshFreq, this);
            }
            //     context.drawImage(imageArray[imgNumber], x, y);
        };

        Class.prototype.playAnimationSequence = function (interval, object) {
            var that = object; // to avoid flobal this in below function
            var timer = setInterval(function () {
                if (that.imgNumber >= that.lastImgNumber) {
                    that.imgNumber = 0;
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    that.animationDone = true;
                    console.log("xxx"+interval);
                } else that.imgNumber++;
            }, interval);
        };


        var d = new Class();
        var d1 = new Class();
        d.startUpAnimation(null, [], 300, 300, 5000, 50);

        d1.startUpAnimation(null,[], 100, 200, 3000, 60);
```

It should work,

Comment: You need to draw the image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it still works the same as before. d1.startUpAnimation uses the interval and timeout of d.startUpAnimation so they still animate at the same rate and time.

Comment: Solved it! Thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, each call to startUpAnimation will draw immediately to the canvas because this execution (your drawImage(..) call) hasn't been included in the callback of the setTimeout or setInterval.